# Native types, critical section and handles not defined in c++ program

Tags: c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, critical-section

I have a compilation problem that I just can't explain in a c++ program on Visual Studio 2012. The error appears at several places in the program, here is an example:

```
#ifndef     __WINMUTEX_H__
# define    __WINMUTEX_H__
# ifdef _WIN32
# include   <windows.h>

namespace Thread
{
class       WinMutex
{
public:
    WinMutex();
    ~WinMutex();
    void    lock();
    void    unlock();
    bool    trylock();
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION    _mutex;
};

typedef WinMutex Mutex;
}
# endif
#endif
```

The compiler gives me an error (C2146). Basically the compiler doesn't seem to find the CRITICAL_SECTION identifier, neither does the Intellisense. As I said, this error occurs in several parts of the program and not just for CRITICAL_SECTION but also for HANDLE and even DWORD.

I tried replacing the windows.h include with the windows 8 equivalent (synchapi.h) but then I still get the error with the addition of the "No target architecture" error.

What's weird is that this code works when I used it in a project on visual studio 2010 on Windows 7.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the _complete_ and _unedited_ error message. Also please point out where in the provided source the errors are.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is a Windows Store app project, some parts of the Win32 API are not available, apparently including CRITICAL_SECTION and related. You'll have to use C++/CX equivalents, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh771042.aspx

Comment: The project is a server so I started with an Empty Project. It is not a Windows Store Project.